# Micronaut Micrometer Prometheus common tag configuration is not applying to all metrics

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micronaut, micronaut-micrometer

Spring Boot allows the declarative configuration of [common tags](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.customizing.common-tags):

> Commons tags are applied to all meters and can be configured, as the
> following example shows:
>
> ```
> management.metrics.tags.region=us-east-1
> ```

Thus, in Spring Boot, with `management.metrics.tags.application=myapp` in place, all metrics include that tag, e.g.:

```
jvm_memory_max_bytes{application="myapp",area="heap",id="G1 Survivor Space"} -1.0
system_cpu_count{application="myapp"} 16.0
```

I want to achieve the same in a Micronaut application. There doesn't seem to be a declarative way to do it and instead, we need to [programatically customize](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-micrometer/latest/guide/#metricsConcepts) it using a `MeterRegistryConfigurer`.

I created the following:

```kotlin
@Singleton
@RequiresMetrics
class PrometheusMeterRegistryConfigurer: MeterRegistryConfigurer<MeterRegistry> {

    override fun configure(meterRegistry: MeterRegistry) {
        meterRegistry.config().commonTags("application", "myapp")
    }

    override fun getType(): Class<MeterRegistry> {
        return MeterRegistry::class.java
    }
}
```

The problem is it isn't applying it to all metrics, some metrics are tagged (`http_server_requests_seconds_max`) while other aren't (`jvm_memory_max_bytes`, `system_cpu_count`, etc.):

```
http_server_requests_seconds_max{application="myapp",exception="none",method="GET",status="200",uri="/actuator/prometheus",} 0.131942121
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'profiled nmethods'",} 1.22023936E8
system_cpu_count 16.0
```

How can I make the tag apply to all micrometer-prometheus metrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding two different `MeterRegistryConfigurer`s:

```kotlin
@Singleton
@RequiresMetrics
class PrometheusMeterRegistryConfigurer: MeterRegistryConfigurer<PrometheusMeterRegistry> {

    override fun configure(meterRegistry: PrometheusMeterRegistry) {
        meterRegistry.config().commonTags("application", "myapp")
    }

    override fun getType(): Class<PrometheusMeterRegistry> {
        return PrometheusMeterRegistry::class.java
    }

}
```

```kotlin
@Singleton
@RequiresMetrics
class CompositeMeterRegistryConfigurer: MeterRegistryConfigurer<CompositeMeterRegistry> {

    override fun configure(meterRegistry: CompositeMeterRegistry) {
        meterRegistry.config().commonTags("application", "myapp")
    }

    override fun getType(): Class<CompositeMeterRegistry> {
        return CompositeMeterRegistry::class.java
    }
}
```